# Visual Studio 2013 search bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to search for :

```
"You must Sign this docmuent."
```

[image]

But VS claims it Cannot be found(in my search I specify entire solution)

But that string is in my code:

```
 if (txtSigString.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                s5ValidationMessage += "You must Sign this docmuent.";
            }
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity is it misspelled in one place and not the other? Did you copy the code as is (with the misspellings in both places)? When you click "find all" does it show it? Works fine in my VS2013.

Comment: Is it possible that you used non-english alphabet? Let's say you cannot find `Yоu must Sign this dосmuеnt` in this page too :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Its true. You must be using a non-english alphabet on the word `You` and `docmuent`

Comment: Also, check your search options.

Comment: Can you try searching for smaller text?  (i. e. search for "You must" and see if it can find it.  Then keep adding additional words and if it stops finding it, then check that word for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to see if you are not using another language character in your text. we had some issue with it trying to understand why MS Access can not sort correctly a field column. After some headache we saw that there were some Russian characters in many field. There are some letters that are present in English and other languages so someone can forget to switch the keyboard language while typing !